# How to create a smoke effect in iphone?

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es, effect

i am developing an application where i want to do some smoke effect like animation and interact with that smoke.

Do i need to implement it OpenGLES or any simple solution?

Is there any sample application for it?

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a simple particle emitter for that. Is it for a Game ? or for another kind of Application ?

It also depends on the level of realism that you're looking for. A guy got down voted for mentioning fluid dynamics, but if you **really** want realism, that's  the best way to go.

Having said that, you can really get decent smoke using a regular particle emitter (you could even try to code it on Core Animation and not in OpenGL ES).

Also, if you're targeting iOS 5.0+, UIKit now includes several Particle FX that you could use, you just have to play with the parameters... checkout this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible with simple solution. You just need to use UIKit particle system. 
Have a look that sample https://github.com/lichtschlag/Dazzle, you just need to check fire and smoke sample.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... i have no knowledge about OpenGLES, but there an alternative called iProcessing is designed to create native interactive apps for iOS, actually there no iOS version  5, actually are iOS 4 and iOS 3, maybe we can wait when they release new version of iOS 5.

You need a mac to use Xcode, iProcessing package includes sample projects for Xcode.

http://luckybite.com/iprocessing/

Honestly, i haven't tried it, but you can compare this code of the interactive smoke  http://processing.org/learning/topics/smoke.html.

Processing is awesome because you can use same codes for Processing.js and iProcessing, but it depends like importing libraries like OpenGL, etc.