# How do I create a smoke effect on the iPhone based on the microphone input?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, quartz-graphics

Hello
I want to make something like "smoke simulator" using iPhone mic.
What is the best and easiest way for doing this? Quartz2D OpenGL or something else?

Comment: Maybe have a look at Cocos2D?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a smoke effect in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123445/how-to-create-a-smoke-effect-in-iphone)

Comment: See also [what is the easiest way to implement particle system without openGL nor cocos2d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784994/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-implement-particle-system-without-opengl-nor-cocos2d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) if you don't mind working with a framework (which is excellent by the by.)

Take a look at the [particle designer](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/tag/particle-effects/)

I highly recommend [Apress' Learn Cocos 2D](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430233039)...

Comment: Yeah but what about the smoke "effect" and the interaction with the user! Does cocos2D support this? I mean, I am going to do something like iSmoke. Is this possible using cocos2D?

Comment: Yes, just download cocos2D, go through the "setup" of it. There's a "ParticleTest" example in there. Try going in and modifying it to the desired "iSmoke" effect. As for user interaction, yes Cocos2D supports it. So get in there and start coding. Your other option is to create your own particle generator.